# Visualização da navbar-brand em smartphones

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, mobile, media-queries

Sou newbie e gostaria de uma ajuda com um problema que estou enfrentando no meu site para mobile. Estou utilizando bootstrap.

Eis o resultado:

[image: navbar]

O texto Squish Monsters está colando na navbar, o resultado correto deveria ser:

[image: navbar]

Obs.:A primeira é em um motorola g4+ e a segunda em um samsung s8+.

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <!-- Toggle button for smartphones -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
         <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
           &#9776;

        </button>
        <!-- GVExperience logo -->
        <a class="navbar-left float-xs-right float-sm-left" href="#"><img src="squishmonsters/img/logo-small2.png" class="imagem img-fluid" alt="gvexperience logo"/></a>

        <!-- Header menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navigation">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-sm-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#who">Key Features</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Screenshots</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR -->
    <!-- LANDING PAGE -->

      <section id="header">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeIn">                
                        <h1>Squish Monsters</h1>
                <p class="subtitle">A game from GVExperinece Company.</p></br>
                <p class="lead">The monsters are calling! Join us in this journey to save the world.</p>
                <div class="paragraph">
                <p class="hidden-sm-down">Designed to be simple and intuitive, just press play and GAME ON!</br>
                Choose between Arcade mode or Staged mode and enjoy 40 different stages to play.</br>
                3 Different maps and 7 differents monsters ready to provide unique and funny moments to you and your friends.</br>
                Power ups that will blow everything up. <i>LITERALLY.</i></p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gvexperience.squishmonsters&hl=en"> <img src="squishmonsters/img/GooglePlay800.png" class="img-fluid" alt="google play download button"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 header-right hidden-sm-down wow fadeIn">
                        <span><img src="squishmonsters/img/bluemonster.png" class="img-fluid" alt="blue monster"/></a></span>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

      </section>

    <!-- END LANDING PAGE -->    

    <!-- KEY FEATURES -->

   <section id="who">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6 wow">
                    <h2>Key Features</h2>
                    <hr align="left" width="50%">
                    <p class="lead">Smash cute monsters in a beautiful world</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Smash cute monsters in a beautiful world.</li>
                        <li>Invite your friends from facebook and check who will have the best score!</li>
                        <li>Play anywhere, anytime, you don't require wifi connection to play!</li>
                        <li>7 different monsters with unique abilities</li>
                        <li>Different Power ups to make the game more enjoyable</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s" data-wow-duration="1s">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/cellphone.png" alt="smartphone with squish monsters"/>
                </div>

            </div>  
        </div>
      </section>

    <!-- END KEY FEATURES-->


    <!-- SCREENSHOTS -->

    <section id="work">
        <div class="container">

        <!-- Title of section -->
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeInUp">
                    <h2>Screenshots</h2>
                    <hr align="left" width="30%">
                    <p class="subtitle">Screenshots taken from real gameplay!</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- CARD 1 -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">

            <div class="card">

                <div class="work-img">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/jungle.png" alt="jungle map">
                </div>

                <div class="card-block">
                    <p class="card-text">Smash as many monsters as you can and improve your score!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

            <!-- END CARD 1 -->

            <!-- CARD 2 -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="work-img">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/frozen.png" alt="frozen map">
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-block">Get bonuses balls to improve your score!</div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END CARD 2 --> 

            <!-- CARD 3 -->
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.7s">

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="work-img">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/texas.png" alt="texas map">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <p class="card-text">Play in different maps with 7 different cute monsters.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- END CARD 3 -->

            <!-- CARD 4 -->

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.9s">

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="work-img">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/explo.png" alt="special effects">
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-block">
                            <p class="card-text">Special powers make everything happen.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <!-- END CARD 4 -->             

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- END SCREENSHOTS -->

    <!-- DOWNLOAD -->

    <section id="download">
        <div class="container wow">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                <h1>Download and play for <b>free</b> now!</h1>
                <hr align="left" width="85%">
                <br>
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gvexperience.squishmonsters&hl=en"> <img src="squishmonsters/img/GooglePlay600.png" class="img-fluid" alt="google play download button"/></a>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- END DOWNLOAD -->


    <!-- FOOTER -->

    <section id="footer">
        <div class="container wow">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">

                    <p><b>About GVexperience</b></p>
                    <p>Founded in 2017 with the mission of create simple and funny games.</p>
                    <p>Our biggest objective is to bring tons of smiles to the world :)!</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/squishmonsters/" target="_blank">Like us: <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <p><b>Say hello:</p></b>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><p><strong><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email: </strong>support@gvexperience.com</p></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>&copy; 2018 Designed by GVexperience</p>
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- END FOOTER -->

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    html,
body {
        height:100%;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

/* For small devices configuration */
@media(max-width:768px) 
{   



    #header {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #header img {
        margin:20% auto 0;
    }
    #who {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #who img {
        margin-top:15%;
    }
    #footer {
        text-align:center;
    }
}

/* NAVBAR configuration */

.navbar {
  background-color:black !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
}

.navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-size:22px;
}

.navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  font-size:23px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    color: white;
}


/*HEADER*/

#header {

    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

#header img {
    padding:0 0 20px;
    width:80%;
}


#header span{
    margin-left:60px;

}

#header .paragraph{

    line-height:2;
}

/*WHO*/

#who {
    padding:5rem 0;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
}

#who li{
    line-height:3;
    font-size: medium;
}

/*WORK*/

#work {
    padding:5rem 0;
}

#work .work-img{
        position:relative;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

}
#work .card-block{
        font-size: small;
}

/*END WORK*/

/*Download*/

#download{
    padding:5rem 0;

}

#download img{
    position:relative;

}

/*FOOTER*/

#footer {
    padding:2rem 0;
    background-color:#484848;
    color:white;
    font-size: small;
}
#footer a {
    color:white;
}

#footer .fa {
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

Agradeço a atenção de todos

Comment: A causa desse problema está relacionada à *Media Query* `@media` em seu **CSS** e a diferença de resolução dos dispositivos utilizados no teste. Entretanto, o **CSS** postado não corresponde ao trecho do **HTML** em sua questão. Por favor, forneça o código correto para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Adicionei todos os trechos do css correspondentes ao navbar e header.

Comment: Mas o problema pode ser no que vem depois do nav, já que o que está apresentando problema não é o nav, mas o texto que vem na div posterior.

Comment: Foi mal, achei que ficaria poluído se eu copiasse o css inteiro. Editei adicionando meu arquivo css full.

Comment: Glauco se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marcar como Resolvido usando o **✓** ao lado das setas a esquerda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jovem seu CSS e HTML tinham alguns probleminhas que estava buggando o seu layout. *(obs: a diferença entre um celular e outro é devido a resolução da tela que no S8 é bem maior!)*

***Agora vamos a resposta.***

**Primeiro**, vc está usando a classe com o nome errado na NavBar. Vc escreveu assim `navbar navbar-fixed-top` e deveria ser apenas `navbar fixed-top` aqui tem a documentação oficial: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#placement

**Segundo**, para usar `position:fixed` na NavBar vc precisa dar uma distancia no Body para o conteúdo que vier abaixo não ficar escondido por baixo da NavBar, vc pode ler sobre esse problema na documentação oficial: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-top

**Terceiro**, vc colocou no `#header` um `height` de 100%. Se vc colocar essa altura vai jogar o conteúdo para fora da página, então removi esse `height` da `#header`

**Agora a melhor parte, o exemplo funcionando *(clique em Executar para ver)***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name=
 content=
>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>

html, body {
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

/* For small devices configuration */
@media(max-width:768px) 
{   
    #header {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #header img {
        margin:20% auto 0;
    }
    #who {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #who img {
        margin-top:15%;
    }
    #footer {
        text-align:center;
    }
}

/* NAVBAR configuration */

.navbar {
  background-color:black !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
}

.navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-size:22px;
}

.navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  font-size:23px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    color: white;
}


/*HEADER*/

#header {

    background-size:cover;
    /* height:100%; */
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

#header img {
    padding:0 0 20px;
    width:80%;
}


#header span{
    margin-left:60px;

}

#header .paragraph{

    line-height:2;
}

/*WHO*/

#who {
    padding:5rem 0;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
}

#who li{
    line-height:3;
    font-size: medium;
}

/*WORK*/

#work {
    padding:5rem 0;
}

#work .work-img{
        position:relative;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

}
#work .card-block{
        font-size: small;
}

/*END WORK*/

/*Download*/

#download{
    padding:5rem 0;

}

#download img{
    position:relative;

}

/*FOOTER*/

#footer {
    padding:2rem 0;
    background-color:#484848;
    color:white;
    font-size: small;
}
#footer a {
    color:white;
}

#footer .fa {
    padding:0 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

        
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <!-- Toggle button for smartphones -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top">
            <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
              &#9776;
   
           </button>
           <!-- GVExperience logo -->
           <a class="navbar-left float-xs-right float-sm-left" href="#"><img src="squishmonsters/img/logo-small2.png" class="imagem img-fluid" alt="gvexperience logo"/></a>
   
           <!-- Header menu -->
           <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navigation">
   
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-sm-right">
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#who">Key Features</a>
                   </li>
   
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Screenshots</a>
                   </li>
   
               </ul>
   
           </div>
       </nav>
       <!-- END NAVBAR -->
       <!-- LANDING PAGE -->
   
         <section id="header">
   
           <div class="container">
   
               <div class="row">
   
                   <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeIn">                
                           <h1>Squish Monsters</h1>
                   <p class="subtitle">A game from GVExperinece Company.</p></br>
                   <p class="lead">The monsters are calling! Join us in this journey to save the world.</p>
                   <div class="paragraph">
                   <p class="hidden-sm-down">Designed to be simple and intuitive, just press play and GAME ON!</br>
                   Choose between Arcade mode or Staged mode and enjoy 40 different stages to play.</br>
                   3 Different maps and 7 differents monsters ready to provide unique and funny moments to you and your friends.</br>
                   Power ups that will blow everything up. <i>LITERALLY.</i></p>
                   </div>
                   <br>
                   <br>
                       <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gvexperience.squishmonsters&hl=en"> <img src="squishmonsters/img/GooglePlay800.png" class="img-fluid" alt="google play download button"/></a>
                   </div>
   
                   <div class="col-md-6 header-right hidden-sm-down wow fadeIn">
                           <span><img src="squishmonsters/img/bluemonster.png" class="img-fluid" alt="blue monster"/></a></span>
                   </div>
   
               </div>
   
           </div>
   
         </section>
   
       <!-- END LANDING PAGE -->    
   
       <!-- KEY FEATURES -->
   
      <section id="who">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
   
                   <div class="col-md-6 wow">
                       <h2>Key Features</h2>
                       <hr align="left" width="50%">
                       <p class="lead">Smash cute monsters in a beautiful world</p>
                       <ul>
                           <li>Smash cute monsters in a beautiful world.</li>
                           <li>Invite your friends from facebook and check who will have the best score!</li>
                           <li>Play anywhere, anytime, you don't require wifi connection to play!</li>
                           <li>7 different monsters with unique abilities</li>
                           <li>Different Power ups to make the game more enjoyable</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
   
                   <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s" data-wow-duration="1s">
                       <img class="img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/cellphone.png" alt="smartphone with squish monsters"/>
                   </div>
   
               </div>  
           </div>
         </section>
   
       <!-- END KEY FEATURES-->
   
   
       <!-- SCREENSHOTS -->
   
       <section id="work">
           <div class="container">
   
           <!-- Title of section -->
               <div class="row">
   
                   <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeInUp">
                       <h2>Screenshots</h2>
                       <hr align="left" width="30%">
                       <p class="subtitle">Screenshots taken from real gameplay!</p>
                   </div>
   
               </div>
   
               <!-- CARD 1 -->
               <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
   
               <div class="card">
   
                   <div class="work-img">
                       <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/jungle.png" alt="jungle map">
                   </div>
   
                   <div class="card-block">
                       <p class="card-text">Smash as many monsters as you can and improve your score!</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
   
               </div>
   
               <!-- END CARD 1 -->
   
               <!-- CARD 2 -->
               <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
   
                   <div class="card">
                       <div class="work-img">
                           <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/frozen.png" alt="frozen map">
                       </div>
   
                       <div class="card-block">Get bonuses balls to improve your score!</div>
   
                   </div>
               </div>
               <!-- END CARD 2 --> 
   
               <!-- CARD 3 -->
                   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.7s">
   
                       <div class="card">
                           <div class="work-img">
                               <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/texas.png" alt="texas map">
                           </div>
                           <div class="card-block">
                               <p class="card-text">Play in different maps with 7 different cute monsters.</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               <!-- END CARD 3 -->
   
               <!-- CARD 4 -->
   
                   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
   
                       <div class="card">
                           <div class="work-img">
                               <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="squishmonsters/img/explo.png" alt="special effects">
                           </div>
   
                           <div class="card-block">
                               <p class="card-text">Special powers make everything happen.</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
   
               <!-- END CARD 4 -->             
   
           </div>
       </section>
       <!-- END SCREENSHOTS -->
   
       <!-- DOWNLOAD -->
   
       <section id="download">
           <div class="container wow">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                   <h1>Download and play for <b>free</b> now!</h1>
                   <hr align="left" width="85%">
                   <br>
                       <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gvexperience.squishmonsters&hl=en"> <img src="squishmonsters/img/GooglePlay600.png" class="img-fluid" alt="google play download button"/></a>
                       <br>
                       <br>
                       <br>
                       <br>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </section>
   
       <!-- END DOWNLOAD -->
   
   
       <!-- FOOTER -->
   
       <section id="footer">
           <div class="container wow">
   
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
   
                       <p><b>About GVexperience</b></p>
                       <p>Founded in 2017 with the mission of create simple and funny games.</p>
                       <p>Our biggest objective is to bring tons of smiles to the world :)!</p>
                           <ul class="list-inline">
                               <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/squishmonsters/" target="_blank">Like us: <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                           </ul>
                   </div>
   
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                       <p><b>Say hello:</p></b>
                           <ul class="list-unstyled">
                               <li><p><strong><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email: </strong>support@gvexperience.com</p></li>
                           </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
   
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                       <p>&copy; 2018 Designed by GVexperience</p>
                   </div>
               </div>           
           </div>
       </section>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque todo o código da navbar dentro de um container:

```
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<!-- Toggle button for smartphones -->
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
     <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
       &#9776;

    </button>
    <!-- GVExperience logo -->
    <a class="navbar-left float-xs-right float-sm-left" href="#"><img src="squishmonsters/img/logo-small2.png" class="imagem img-fluid" alt="gvexperience logo"/></a>

    <!-- Header menu -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navigation">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-sm-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#who">Key Features</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Screenshots</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
</div>
<!-- END NAVBAR -->
```